# StrongLoop overriding PUT built in method

Tags: strongloop, overriding

I am facing an issue trying to override StrongLoop built in method for PUT request.

So in model.js file I am using:

```
  Model.on('attached', function(){
    Model.updateAttributes = function(data, id, cb){
      cb(null,'This is a overridden method');
    }; 
}
```

But when I call the endpoint with a PUT /api/v1/models/1 and payload this function does not get executed but the built in one. I also tried to use other function instead of updateAttributes but without any success like for example:

```
Model.updateAll = function([where], data, cb) {
  cb(null, 'this is a overriden method');
}

Model.create = function(data, cb) {
  cb(null, 'this is overriden method');
}
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of overriding the method, you can disable and attach a new method to the same endpoint as follows:

```
Model.disableRemoteMethodByName('updateAttributes');

Model.newMethod = function(cb) {
  cb(null, 'new message');
}

Model.remoteMethod('newMethod', {
  returns: {
    arg: 'msg'
  },
  http: {
    verb: 'put',
    path: '/'
  }
});
```

Comment: I had a warning stating that `disableRemoteMethod` is now deprecated and now `disableRemoteMethodByName` should be used. Once I used that, I was able to successfully override the built-in method. Thanks very much!

Comment: Glad it worked out! I'll edit my answer to reflect the new API